# How to read .xlsx file using XLConnect in R

Tags: r, xlconnect

I want to read an .xls or .xlsx file from my hard drive using R.  I installed the XLConnect package and have received the following errors:

```
Data <- readWorksheet(loadWorkbook("C:/test1.xlsx"),sheet=1)
Error: FileNotFoundException (Java): File 'test1.xlsx' could not be found - you may specify to automatically create the file if not existing.
```

I want to read the first tab of my Excel file.  I also tried the gdata `read.xls` function and failed.

Comment: Looks like that path you specified to the file is not correct. I would double (and triple) check that. (Maybe try backslash instead of forward slash?)

Comment: You might also check out `readxl` and `openxlsx`, which don't require Java.

Comment: Wrong path... close as typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your working directory before calling the xlsx file. So use the function setwd before calling the file. Example:

```
setwd("the location where the file is placed on your pc")
Data <- readWorksheet(loadWorkbook("C:/test1.xlsx"),sheet=1)
```

Note: make sure u are using forward slashes instead of backwards slashes in the setwd function.